# How to get the list of post of a Facebook Page with number of views?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got a problem of getting the number of view of page posts.

"GET /v2.8/{page_id}/feed" could give me the list of page posts.
But I also want the number of views of each posts.

Trying "GET /v2.8/{page_id}/insights/post_impressions,post_consumptions_unique"
but the return is empty set.

Am I missing some param?

Comment: I got it. Missing Permission "post_impressions".

Comment: But can I get the view count together with the post list, so I do not have to ask the view count for every post in the list?

Answer (score 1):

> [from comments] But can I get the view count together with the post list, so I do not have to ask the view count for every post in the list?

Insights are available via the post object, too, so you can use [field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion) to get the data in one request:

```
/{page-id}/feed?fields=message,insights.metric(post_impressions,post_consumptions_unique)
```